# jQuery Mobile on('pageinit') not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using latest jQuery Mobile 1.3.0, if I try this on the console I see the alert

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

But If I try this code

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

I dont see the alert and I get a `[>#document]` object result.

Any idea what is causing this and how to show display the alert?

I'm trying this simple example because using `on('pageshow')` does not seem to be triggering the methods when visiting the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im confused by your title, are you using `pageinit` or `pageshow`?
Because `pageinit` works perfectly for me.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: I was used a customized version of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: I had somehow problems to get `pageshow` working as mentioned in the docs. So I used `pageinit`.

Answer (score 0):

In pageshow call,we must use pageinit method 
The following code working fine in our project.

```
$('#HomePage').live('pageinit', function() 
                    {
                    }
                );

$('#HomePage').live('pageshow', function() 
                    {
                        alert('pageshow method call');
                    }
                );
```

Comment: live method was deprecated since jquery 1.7 and removed since jquery 1.9